# Error: Type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred

Tags: vb.net

I previously worked on a C# project and now I'm basically doing the same project but in vb.net.

C# code:
Manager class

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Reads file from binary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="the filepath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Animal[] ReadFile(string filename)
    {
        BinSerializerUtility BinSerial = new BinSerializerUtility();
        var animals = BinSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<Animal>(filename);
        return animals.ToArray();
    }
```

class  BinaryFileDeSerialize

```
public List<T> BinaryFileDeSerialize<T>(string filePath) where T : class
    {
        var list = new List<T>();

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The file" + " was not found. ", filePath);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();

            while (fileStream.Position < fileStream.Length)
                list.Add((T)b.Deserialize(fileStream));
        }


        return list;
    }
```

Everything worked fine in C#, however in the vb.net there was a problem.

I tried doing it this way in vb.net:

Manager class:

```
 Public Function ReadFile(ByVal filename As String) As Animal()
            Dim BinSerial As BinSerializerUtility = New BinSerializerUtility
            Dim animals = BinSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize(filename)
            Return animals.ToArray
        End Function
```

From the code above I'm getting an error:

> Type parameter 'T' for 'Public Function BinaryFileDeSerialize(Of T As
>   Class)(filePath As String) As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T)'
>   cannot be inferred.

vb.net class BinaryFileDeSerialize:

```
  Public Function BinaryFileDeSerialize(Of T As {Class})(ByVal filePath As String) As List(Of T)
            Dim list = New List(Of T)
            If Not File.Exists(filePath) Then
                Throw New FileNotFoundException(("The file" + " was not found. "), filePath)
            End If
            Dim fileStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)
            Dim b As BinaryFormatter = New BinaryFormatter

            While (fileStream.Position < fileStream.Length)
                list.Add(CType(b.Deserialize(fileStream), T))

            End While
            Return list
        End Function
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call

```vb
Dim animals = BinSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize(Of <put your type here>)(filename)
```

So if your type is Animal*, use

```vb
Dim animals = BinSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize(Of Animal)(filename)
```

*after your recent edit

---

Already from the beginning, you can help your project to be without type-related complications. Write [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) as the first line of your class file. It will require you to declare every variable with
`As <type>` and its pay-off is aplication which can be more easily read, maintained and kept free from type-related errors.

So after adding `Option Explicit`, you have to add type declaration:

```vb
Dim animals As List(Of Animal) = BinSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize(Of Animal)(filename)
```

You immediately get better overview of what you are doing.

Comment: Just a note: Option Explicit On does not force the `As <type>` if you also use Option Infer On.

Answer (score 1):

In the C# version the type parameter for the generic method was supplied:

```
BinSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<Animal>(filename);
```

It needed to be, since `filename` is just a string and there's no other way to infer the parameter.  But in the VB version it's not being supplied:

```
BinSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize(filename)
```

It still needs to be, for the same reason:

```
BinSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize(Of Animal)(filename)
```