# Working with a derived property inside base class

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, inheritance

I'm working on a project and find myself lacking in OOP knowledge:

I want to use a base class method that contains common code for all the derived classes. The thing is that the properties it needs to work on are of different type in each derived class, and so it doesn't "see" them inside the base class. For example:

```
Public Interface IBase
    Function CommonMethod() As Integer
End Interface

Public MustInherit Class BaseProperties
    Public Property prop1 As String
    Public Property prop2 As String
End Class

Public Class ActualProperties1 : Inherits BaseProperties
    Public Property prop3 As String
    Public Property prop4 As String
End Class

Public MustInherit Class BaseClass : Implements IBase
    'placeholder for the actual PropertyClass class defined in each derived class
    Public Overridable Property PropertyClass As Object 
    Public Function CommonMethod() As Integer Implements IBase.CommonMethod
        Dim Varis as String = ""
        'This correctly shows the derived class name
        MsgBox(Me.GetType.Name)
        'This throws an exception, as it is referencing the base class object which is nothing
        MsgBox(Me.PropertyClass.GetType.Name)
        'This is closer to what I actually want to do. 
        For Each prop As ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor In ComponenModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Me.PropertyClass)
            If prop.PropertyType.ToString = "System.String" Then
                Varis += prop.GetValue()
                prop.SetValue(Me.PropertyClass, "")
            End If
        Next
        'Do something with Varis
    End Function
End Class

Public Class DerivedClass : Inherits BaseClass
    Public Property PropertyClass As ActualProperties1
    Public Sub New()
        PropertyClass = New ActualProperties1
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Dim cli As New DerivedClass
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        cli.prop1 = "test"
        cli.prop4 = "test"
        cli.CommonMethod()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And there are a few other classes that inherit from BaseClass, and that have their own set of properties that augment BaseProperties that are not common to the others, but the CommonMethod() operations will be the same for all classes.

Basically I want to avoid:

- Code duplication, writing the same code in every derived class
- Calling the base method with the actual property as a parameter like this CommonMethod(PropertyClass) , unless you guys tell me there's not other way to do it... just doesn't feels right?

I've looked around and seems this is not possible without doing yet another class, but I'm not sure since the answers were in C#, so there's a chance this is a duplicate.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: That is not how inheritance works. The base class is not to know of different properties of the derived classes.

Comment: The base class would include code and properties that all the derived ones use.  *But* if a base class method needs something from a derived class, almost by definition that method belongs in the other class.  That `As Object` declaration would bug me.  Also, rather than Inheritance *and* Interfaces, see if you cant get the same thing in a simpler form with MustOveride

Comment: What you are asking is done all the time in c#.  In c# the object 'T' is used in the base class to define a generalized type then 'T' is automatically replaced with the derived type in each inherited class.  For VB.NET see the following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864200/error-type-parameter-t-cannot-be-inferred

Comment: OneFineFriday- I know that, so I don't want to know each individual property, I basically want to iterate them or pass the object to another function without knowing each individual property name.

Comment: When more than one person comments, you need to use @ as in @OneFineDay to ping them.  Keep in mind all this code to `iterate and pass objects` makes it more convoluted and complex - and is just replacing the duplicated code.

Comment: @Plutonix, thanks for the tip. I edited the code to show what I mean with "Iterating".

Comment: No no no no.  Reflection is not the answer to your design problem.  If CommonMethod needs prop data from derived classes either a) it isnt all that Common and should be propagated to the derived classes or b) some or all the prop data should be on the base class.

Comment: ...or the child classes could call the protected parent version with params: `MyBase.CommonMethod(parm1, prop4, prop6value)`.  So most of the important code would be in the base class   (Your starting point is a little too abstract for me at this hour)

Comment: Use a `MustOverride` property on the baseclass.  That will force the sub classes to implement the property.  Each sub class should know enough about its self to be able to calculate it.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking us what's wrong with your solution, why don't you try explaining your *actual* problem. Also `prop.PropertyType.ToString = "System.String"` is a bad idea,  `prop.PropertyType Is GetType(System.String)` is the correct way.

Comment: @Plutonix, I mentioned that calling the base method with derived params didn't feel right to me, but I guess it is the better choice...

Comment: @BradleyUffner, I want to avoid writing the same method in all the derived classes -it does exactly the same thing, but with each class property set. Also, MustOverride forces me to use the same Type in the base and in the derived, and they are not...

Comment: @KalaNag If it uses a different source property then they are NOT doing exactly the same thing.  Look at my answer below to see that the implementation is different for each sub class.

Comment: @jdweng I understand that I can't use a Generic in a Property, unless I make a whole Generic class, right?

Comment: @BradleyUffner the calculations done over the properties are the same... Is there no way to do this other than repeat the same code in n classes? If the operation changes, it has to be changed in all the derived classes?

Comment: @KalaNag If the code is exactly the same for each sub class then the code belongs in the base class, but that seems to directly contradict your statement that each subclass needs to calculate its value differently.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I did mention in the post that "And there are a few other classes that inherit from BaseClass, and that have their own set of properties that augment BaseProperties that are not common to the others, **but the CommonMethod() operations will be the same for all classes.**". English is not my primary language so I'm sorry if this was confusing.

Comment: @KalaNag I don't really see how that changes anything.  Perhaps the problem is that we don't understand your question enough.  Maybe you should go back and try to reword it (or start another question) in a way that makes it clear what you actually want to result to be.  I think your example code showing how you /think/ it should work is adding a lot of confusion to the discussion.  Try showing us what you want the usage of the classes to be without showing what you think the internals should look like.

Comment: @BradleyUffner thank you, will do so tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

A base class shouldn't know anything about its sub classes.  What you can do, is define a common function on the base class and mark it `MustOverride`, which will force sub classes to implement it.  Each sub class implementation knows about its own structure and can calculate the derived property as needed.  You can do this for Properties, Functions, and Subs.

See this example I just threw together:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim Thing1 As BaseClass = New DerivedClass1 With {.NumberOfCows = 10}

        Dim Thing2 As BaseClass = New DerivedClass2 With {.NumberOfGoats = 5, .NumberOfChickens = 20}

        Console.WriteLine(Thing1.CalculateNumberOfAnimals()) 'Prints 10
        Console.WriteLine(Thing2.CalculateNumberOfAnimals()) 'Prints 25
    End Sub

    Public MustInherit Class BaseClass
        Public MustOverride Function CalculateNumberOfAnimals() As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class DerivedClass1
        Inherits BaseClass

        Public Property NumberOfCows As Integer

        Public Overrides Function CalculateNumberOfAnimals() As Integer
            Return NumberOfCows
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class DerivedClass2
        Inherits BaseClass

        Public Property NumberOfChickens As Integer
        Public Property NumberOfGoats As Integer

        Public Overrides Function CalculateNumberOfAnimals() As Integer
            Return NumberOfChickens + NumberOfGoats
        End Function
    End Class

End Module
```

Comment: Updated example to make it more clear that the code is actually flowing through the `BaseClass`.